# Usage of "going to be"

Tags: grammaticality, future

Is the following grammatically correct?

> Hi All,
> Today I am ***going to be sending*** this model of living room

Comment: The "going to be" part sounds okay, but "sending this model of living room" sounds wrong.

Comment: "The" or "a" seems to be missing here. "I'll send" is more natural.

Comment: "Today I am going to be sending this model of living room" reveals one minor and one major problem.

"I am going to be sending…” is fine, grammatically. Colloquially it belongs almost exclusively to Indian English… which might well be just what you want.

“… this model of living room" will generally be wrong, unless it is justified by context which doesn’t appear in the example.

You might use “… this model of living room today, that one tomorrow and the other next week…” but that’s a different idea.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin But here the person who says this American/Brit I guess. So I thought whether its correct grammatically. Usually i say: I will send this model soon or I will send this model by today. I understand that this statement in question is emphasizing that "going to be" seems kind of certainty of activity that he/she is about to do. So want to clarify this.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs.and and nnnnn Thanks for your answer. I agree that its supposed to be "the", actually its my mistake that I used "this" I mainly want to know whether "going to be" is proper. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @Karth It’s highly unlikely anyone who used that style would be American or British, 

If you see no difference between “Today I am going to be sending…” and “I will send this soon…”  or “I will send this by today…” please say so.

Can you re-phrase “I understand that this statement in question is emphasizing that ‘going to be’ seems kind of certainty of activity that he/she is about to do. So want to clarify this…” to work in English?

If you see no problem with "the model of living room” please say so.

Can you not see, "going to be" in that context will rarely work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Bitter dreggs' comment, in that "the" or "a" is missing before "living room".

As for "going to be sending", it is absolutely fine.

Using a future continuous form (whether "going to be sending" or "will be sending") implies that it will happen as a matter of course, whereas a simple form ("going to send" or "will send") implies volition.

The English language is rich in future forms, giving us a wide spectrum of often subtle shades of meaning.